# How to remove namespace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I have this on my request soapenv:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I want to remove **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"**

Can I do that from my Service_BindingStub?
Maybe can set org.apache.axis.client.Call object with some property... I don't know.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the namespace?

Comment: I really dont know. The programmer who develop that webservice tell me, that namespace its wrong.

Comment: If the `xsi` prefix is *not* used anywhere, that declaration being there won't make any difference, but if any element in the XML uses the `xsi` prefix (in a `xsi:type` attribute, for example), removing that namespace declaration will make it invalid.

Comment: Exactly. Im according with you. That prefix is not used in the xml. But, the ws programmer told me if I could remove it from my request xml.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue to have **xsi namespace** in the root so extend `SoapSerializationEnvelope` and then override method: `write` like:

```
@Override
    public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
//        writer.setPrefix("i", this.xsi);
        writer.setPrefix("d", this.xsd);
        writer.setPrefix("c", this.enc);
        writer.setPrefix("v", this.env);
        writer.startTag(this.env, "Envelope");
        writer.startTag(this.env, "Header");
        this.writeHeader(writer);
        writer.endTag(this.env, "Header");
        writer.startTag(this.env, "Body");
        this.writeBody(writer);
        writer.endTag(this.env, "Body");
        writer.endTag(this.env, "Envelope");
    }
```